# Printing binary representation of a negative integer

Tags: format

I am trying to print the binary representation of a negative integer in C using the printf function. However, I'm having trouble finding the correct format specifier for negative integers. Here's the code snippet I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = -13;
    printf("%b", a);
    return 0;
}
```

I have got warning. I used %b, is that correct format specifier and how the negative numbers are stored in the memory.